# How to turn off automatic closing paren in Clion

Tags: settings, parentheses, clion

How do I turn off automatic closing parentheses (in C/C++)? There are "insert pair bracket" and "insert pair quote" options under Settings/Editor/General/Smart Keys. Both are unchecked. But I see nothing about parentheses. It wouldn't be a big deal if CLion would just overtype its automatic ones when I also type the closing paren. As is I end up with two closing braces every time. I spend more time configuring jetbrains products than I actually do writing code...zzzzzz.

Using CLion 1.2 on Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Insert pair bracket" in Settings/Editor/General/Smart Keys does the job in Clion 1.2.4.

Comment: ah yes too smart for it's own good.  I also have a bear with automatic quotes. actually auto brackets of any kind. One gets into patterns and many don't fit what the clever geek was thinking.  I often type something then put the brackets after. or paste code and add quotes and brackets. etc. The brain gets used to how an editor works and I use a number of them.  Really awful when one types a quote or some bracket you get a pair then backspace deletes BOTH.  It's like auto spell corrupting on phones :)

Comment: This actually doesn't turn of all of this; I still get FULL PAIR of parentheses when auto-completing a method name. Insane.

I really wish there was a way to DISABLE ALL AUTO-TYPING in JetBrains (and MS) products. It might be useful to some people but I tend to turn off most of it (if not all) anyway... it disrupts my workflow. Auto-complete, yes, auto-insert characters, please no.

Comment: As of 2023.1.1...search "insert pair '}'". Search "insert paired bracket" for square brackets and parentheses.